# convert autocad shx font to true type font

Tags: autocad

dears i am using Autocad 2019 and a lot of text with .SHX style, these text are in Arabic language i want to convert them into true type font, if i change font style the arabic characters become English characters.
Any idea!!
also i have an idea but i don't know if this possible or not! first change SHX to true type font, then write small script that rematch all English characters to Arabic characters as shown in screen. i know a little about Python, but don't know if Autocad support python or not.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFa3B.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you will need a routine that will translate the characters in the current text string to the correct character in the true type font.  .SHX is old school and is ASCII based. All of the characters have a decimal value of between 32 and 127 (could be 255, I do not exactly recall).  These decimal values, when displayed using a true type font equate to standard English characters.
I do not know of a routine that already does this but search for a "AutoLisp" routine (AutoCAD's default scripting language) that may do this - there are hundreds of existing AutoLisp routines.
If a routine does not already exist, one of the web sites that have AutoList routines can make a custom routine (unless you chose to make one your self - AutoLisp is a fairly easy lanugage to learn - except it Lisp based).
Web sites, for example, that have AutoLisp routines: http://www.lee-mac.com/programs.html or [Jeffery Sanders](http://www.jefferypsanders.com/autolisp.html) or [CAD Studio](https://www.cadstudio.cz/freeware)